# ID column not working in query string

Tags: asp.net

i am using repeater to bind data. all column bound successfully but when i am using ID column in query string to take forward value of ID column in next page its not working.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptBooks" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr style="background-color:#f3f5f6;width:700px">
                <td align="center" >
                    <asp:Image ID="Pic" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                    <br />              
                </td>
                <td align="right">           
                    <p>I want to:</b> <%#Eval("i_want_to")%><br />
                    <p>Price:</b> <%#Eval("expected_price")%><br />
                    <p>City:</b> <%#Eval("city")%><br />
                    <p>Property Type:</b> <%#Eval("property_type")%><br />
                    <p>Bedroom:</b> <%#Eval("bedroom")%><br />
                    <p>Description:</b> <%#Eval("property_Description")%><br />
                <td style="float:right"><a href="detail.aspx?img="<%#Eval("id")%>" style="color:Red">more...</a></td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Hyperlink` control and set the `NavigateUrl` accordingly.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
     NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","~/detail.aspx?img={0}") %>' Text="more..." />
```

Comment: i edited your like this: NavigateUrl='~/detail.aspx?img=<%# Eval("id") %>' its not working

Comment: @mukeshvishwas: so my answer didn't work either? using: `NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","~/detail.aspx?img={0}") %>'`

Comment: @mukeshvishwas Describe "not working". What is it not doing that it should be doing? What does the result look like? Does it throw any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the double quote before your Eval so it looks like this.

```
<td style="float:right"><a href="detail.aspx?img=<%#Eval("id")%>" style="color:Red">more...</a></td>
```